# Just started learning C++

Tags: c++

Write a program to help me compute the sum. Your program should prompt me to enter numbers until I’m done (when I’m done I’ll enter -1). Then your program should print out the sum.

```
#include<iostream>

  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
        double sum;
        double number;
        double total;



        while (number !=-1)
    {
    cout<<"Input numbers: "<<endl;
    cin>>number;
    total+=number;
    }
    sum = total + number;
    cout<<"The sum is "<<sum<<endl;
    return 0;

  }
```

For example I enter 9 and 9 then -1 I get 25. Would I just make double total =2; it works but don't really understand why it outputs 25. What is wrong in my code? I just started learning appreciate the help.

Comment: Always initialise your variables.

Comment: When the loop starts what is the initial value of `number` (or the other variables)? In C++ uninitialized variables really are *uninitialized*. Their values will be *indeterminate* and could be seen as random or garbage. Using uninitialized variables lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: why need this line `sum = total + number;`  .  after exiting the loop the  variable `total` has the sum.

Comment: Can somebody find a duplicate for this? If not, create an answer and it will become a heavily used duplicate...

Answer (score 4):

C++ doesn't automatically initialize declared variables to zero, and since variables are just labels on memory locations, you get the numerical conversion of whatever bits happen to be stored in that location as the de facto initialization. So make a habit of always initializing variables:

```
double sum = 0;
double total = 0;
double number = 0;
```

Notice this is really only a problem with your total variable, as the others are all assigned values before being used in an operation (by cin and by =, the assignment operator). (Edit: missed the while loop using number! See comment) It's still (always) a good idea to initialize at declaration.

Comment: Where is `number` written before `while (number !=-1)`. I don't see it...

Comment: Ah right that while loop... see that's why you always initialize variables! You're going to miss something sooner or later. QED.

Comment: Write that into the question. It will provide a really nice insight for new programmers.

Answer (score 2):

What you are missing from C++, is the initialization.

If you use a variable before initializing it, your program will have [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). From there on anything can happen.

You can solve it simply by e.g.

```
double sum = 0;
```

Remember to do it for all of your variables.

You don't need this line too:

```
sum = total + number;
```

`total` is already the `sum`.

Answer (score 2):

`sum`, `number`, and `total` are all uninitialized. That means they don't necessarily have `0` in them when they start.

To fix this, just set them to `0`:

```
double sum = 0;
double number = 0;
double total = 0;
```

---

**Note:** I should warn you that I don't recommend comparing a float/double to an integer like `-1` as a general rule because [it can behave unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). However, I think you should probably be fine in this case. But that isn't a guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

A few more remarks aside that you should initialise your variables.

- I think you don't like to subtract 1 form your result. If you enter `-1` it will be added to `total` and than the while  condition will be `false` and the loop ends. Thus, your result is wrong.
- You don't need `total` and `sum`.
- Make the scope of your variables as small as possible. `number` only needs the loop body as scope.
- Don't use `using namespace std`.
- Formatting of your code matters. I always use a tool such as clang-format.

Here my refactoring of your code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double sum = 0;

    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Input numbers: " << std::endl;
        double number = 0;
        std::cin >> number;
        if (number == -1) {
            break;
        }
        sum += number;
    }

    std::cout << "The sum is " << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you enter -1, then two things happens: It usees the value to calculate the new sum (minus one) and after the while - } the loop will quit and continue...
This and the other comments will make your programm work.